# C++ Printing a map in a case-insensitive, alphabetical order

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, dictionary, alphabetical

I have a:

```
map<string, map<int,int>>
```

Is there a way to print the contents of this map in alphabetical order, but case insensitive? For example, have it print in the following order:

```
A : 1:1, 2:2
a : 3:1
an : 2:1
And : 4:1
and : 3:1
```

Currently, I am printing using the following:

```
for (auto it = tokens.begin(); it != tokens.end(); ++it){
    cout << it->first << " : ";
    auto const &internal_map = it->second;
    for (auto it2 = internal_map.begin(); it2 != internal_map.end(); ++it2){
        if (it2 != internal_map.begin())
            cout << " , ";
        cout << it2->first << ":" << it2->second;
    }       
    cout << endl;
}
```

This prints everything, however, it goes through all uppercase first, followed by all lowercase. For example:

```
A : 1:1, 2:2
And : 4:1
a : 3:1
an : 2:1
and : 3:1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to print the contents of this map in alphabetical order, but case insensitive?

Yes.

1. You will have to create a custom compare functor that compares two strings in a case insensitive manner.

   ```
   struct cicompare
   {
      bool operator()(std::string const& lhsIn, std::string const& rhsIn) const
      {
        char const* lhs = lhsIn.c_str();
        char const* rhs = rhsIn.c_str();
        for ( ; *lhs != '\0' && *rhs != '\0'; ++lhs, ++rhs )
        {
           if ( tolower(*lhs) != tolower(*rhs) )
           {
              return ( tolower(*lhs) < tolower(*rhs) );
           }
           else if ( *lhs != *rhs)
           {
              if ( *(lhs+1) == '\0' && *(rhs+1) == '\0' )
              {
                 return (*lhs < *rhs);
              }
           }
        }
        return (tolower(*lhs) < tolower(*rhs));
      }
   };
   ```
2. Use the case insensitive compare functor to create the map.

   ```
   map<string, map<int,int>, cicompare> mymap;
   ```
3. If you don't want to store your map ordered in a case insensitive manner, create a copy of the original map using `cicompare` just before printing and print the new map.

   ```
   map<string, map<int,int>, cicompare> mapForPrinting;
   mapForPrinting.insert(originalMap.start(), originalMap.end());
   ```

Comment: This could well be good but is fundamentally different in that it changes the container storage order, rather than a one-off iteration ordering while printing.  Your comparison will run off the end of identical strings though, and as is the second `return` statement can never be reached.

Comment: Notice that the example in the question had both `A` and `a` as elements. Using a case-insensitive comparison would only allow one of them.

Comment: @TonyD thank you for figuring out the logic error. It's fixed now.

Comment: @MarkRansom ditto what I said to Tony D.

Comment: I actually think your comparison function was better the first time around; I disagree with Tony that there was a problem with it. What happens now if you compare two strings that start with "A"?

Comment: @MarkRansom code was `for ( ; ; ++c_lhs, ++c_rhs )
if (tolower(*c_lhs) < tolower(*c_rhs)) return true;` - how did you expect that to terminate without overrun in the `lhs == rhs` case (for which the comparison must yield per `!(X < Y) && !(Y < X)`?  Solid find on the "Abc" vs "ADE" BTW - my answer was broken too (can't believe I spent half an hour coding without thinking it through O_o - appreciate the insight.  Cheers.

Comment: @TonyD, you're right - I didn't consider the case where `c_rhs` is shorter than `c_lhs` or signed characters that are less than 0. I withdraw my disagreement. I'm not convinced the replacement works either though.

Comment: @MarkRansom no, it's not quite right yet.  The else if clause can be completely removed, and the final return can be for !*lhs && *rhs so it works for signed char.

Comment: @TonyD I posted a second answer with a comparison function that I put a lot of thought into - see what you think.

Comment: From what I can tell, this achieves what I was trying to do. However, I don't quite understand how using a functor to order the map works. This is the first I have ever heard of function objects (or realized there was a version of map with the third parameter, or considered how map's are sorted) and have been reading a few articles, but wanted to clarify.. When adding each new key to the map, does the new key get compared one by one to each current key, starting at the beginning of the map, until it finds one that it is less than (or whatever is stipulated in the functor), for insertion?

Comment: @CGutz a map is based on a tree structure so it doesn't compare against every key, only about log(n) of them. And I think this comparison function has some problems, e.g. "AxB" and "AXB" are considered the same.

Comment: Yes, it is close, but does have a bug. It treats "After" and "after" the same, although it does catch the difference between "A" and "a". So it is not always catching cases where the word is the same, but different cases.

Comment: Added the following line before the for loop to fix:

if (_stricmp(left.c_str(), right.c_str()) == 0){return left > right;}

Answer (score 5):

As stated in the accepted answer, you want to use a `map` with a custom comparison function. The trick is getting the proper comparison. You don't want a totally case-insensitive comparison or "And" and "and" would be equal, allowing only one of them in the map. Your sample data doesn't cover all cases; for example what would be the order of "An", "And", "AN", "AND"? The following comparison function orders them "AN", "An", "AND", "And" - shorter strings are always less than longer strings of the same characters, and the first character that has different case is a tie-breaker with upper-case before lower-case.

```
struct CaseAwareCompare
{
    bool operator()(const char * left, const char * right) const
    {
        bool tied = true, tiebreaker = false;
        for (int i = 0; left[i] != 0; ++i)
        {
            if (right[i] == 0)
                return false;
            if (tolower(left[i]) != tolower(right[i]))
                return tolower(left[i]) < tolower(right[i]);
            if (tied && left[i] != right[i])
            {
                tied = false;
                tiebreaker = left[i] < right[i];
            }
        }
        return (right[i] != 0) || (!tied && tiebreaker);
    }

    bool operator()(const string & left, const string & right) const
    {
        return operator()(left.c_str(), right.c_str());
    }
};
```

I struggled with what to call this; it's not a case-insensitive comparison because it differentiates between inputs with different case. I finally decided it should be called a case-aware comparison.

Comment: +1 I hadn't looked at the question for so long I'd forgotten it had to support 'A' and 'a' etc..  Looks very solid indeed.

Answer (score 0):

You can store the data in a vector. You can store the data as a `structure` or `pair` in the vector. If you use a `pair` then,

```
vector< pair< string, map<int,int> > > needToSort;
```

Then you can call the `std::sort` in it.

```
sort(needToSort.begin(), needToSort.end(), compareFunction);
```

The `compareFunction` is,

```
bool compareFunction( pair< string, map<int,int> > firstElement, pair< string, map<int,int> > secondElement)
{
    string firstString = firstElement.first;
    string secondString = secondElement.first;
    for(int i=0;i<firstString.size();i++)
        firstString[i] = toLower(firstString [i]);

    for(int i=0;i<secondString.size();i++)
        secondString [i] = toLower(secondString[i]);

   return firstString < secondString;
}
```

and then you can print the vector which should give you the desired result.

Answer (score 0):

I think the usual way to do this is to create an index of iterators to the elements to be displayed:

```
// Return a range of iterators to the elements
// of the given range.
template <typename Range>
auto make_index(Range& range)
  -> vector<decltype(range.begin())> {
  vector<decltype(range.begin())> index;
  for (auto i = begin(range), e = end(range); i != e; ++i) {
    index.push_back(i);
  }
  return index;
}
```

and sort the iterators according to the display criteria:

```
auto index = make_index(tokens);
using iterator = decltype(tokens.begin());
sort(begin(index), end(index), [](iterator a, iterator b){
  return boost::algorithm::ilexicographical_compare(a->first, b->first);
});
```

remembering to dereference the iterators for display:

```
cout << "Sorted:\n";
for (auto&& i : index) {
  cout << i->first << ':';
  for (auto const& j : i->second) {
    cout << ' ' << j.first << ':' << j.second;
  }
  cout << '\n';
}
```

[(See it all live at Coliru)](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/06bb7363a7f151b0).

I've used [`boost::algorithm::ilexicographical_compare`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_55_0/doc/html/boost/algorithm/ilexicographical_compare.html), Boost's case-insensitive locale-dependent string comparison, to save some typing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a custom "case aware" comparator, as [proposed by Mark Ransom](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22952216/8123074), that follows the alphabetical order of your language (or even your own alphabetical order implementation) with Unicode, you can use std::collate or boost::collator.

```
struct CaseAwareCompare
{        
    operator()(const std::string& strLeft, const std::string& strRight) const
    {
        using namespace boost::locale;

        std::locale loc;

        // Quaternary level : consider all case, accents, and punctuation.
        // The words must be identical in terms of Unicode representation.
        if (-1 == use_facet<collator<char> >(loc).compare(collator_base::quaternary,                                                               strLeft.begin(),
                                                          strLeft.end(),
                                                          strRight.begin(),
                                                          strRight.end())) {
    
            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }    
};
```

**Note:** you could need to use the collator_base::identical level or use normalized Unicode strings depending on your application.
As an example, with two different strings (non-matching code points) but with the same Unicode representation (displayed to the user).
"señor" : with ñ.
"señor" : with n + ◌̃.

- **Without normalization** and **with collator_base::quaternary**, the two
  strings would be in the same map element.
- **Without normalization** and **with collator_base::identical**, the two
  strings would be in different map elements, but if you display the
  map elements to the user, he could not understand why there is twice
  the same string.
- **With all the strings normalized** in your application, the two strings
  would not be different anymore and you can
  use collator_base::quaternary without worries.